# Publish c# project with database exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I've written an app which is working with local database. In my computer, it works perfectly. I published it and I was checking the setup to install the perequisites like .net framework 4.5.1 and SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB.

I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occured. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

There is my connection string:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(system32.Properties.Settings.Default.thedatabaseConnectionString);
```

Should I modify the string to a generic path to get this working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So have you checked what the connection string is on the machine that doesn't work? Does the machine have a LocalDB instance to connect to, up and running? Basically you need to do some diagnostic work to find out exactly why it isn't working.

Comment: have you modified the connection string with the proper IP/port/username and password?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I guess so. Both .mdf and .ldf are required on installing, I don't wonder why it is not working. Forgot to mention, I've tried the app on another PC, there was the point it wasn't working anymore.

Comment: Did you try to launch your application on the same machine where sql server is running ? If it works there then check if SQL server allows remote connections.

Comment: @DotNetFan, the thing is there is no remote. In the setup will be the database, as well. I guess I'm just needing a generic connectionstring to get this right.